# How to ensure schema compatibility between EF Model Snapshot and current database schema?

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

Considering a .NET development using code-first approach to create and update the database schema state, I'll provide my last scenario with migrations to clarify my question.

After some development, I made some modifications to the database schema and performed `Add-Migration` command, leading to a new migration.

However, the modifications I made included both changing the name of a table and adding new properties to the same table. As I expected, the Entity Framework migration handler, instead of correctly creating instructions within the new migration to rename the table and add the extra columns, it dropped the table with the old name and created a new one with a new name and new columns.

Realizing that I would then need to manually edit the migration, I changed the instructions that drops and creates the table in both Up and Down to instructions that would rename the table. The thing is that suddenly I forgot to add those new columns, and then, when I ran `Update-Database`, I had the table correctly renamed but without the extra columns.

In my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong): `Add-Migration` scans the models inside `DbContext` to generate a new migration and thus updating the model snapshot, while `Update-Database` only compares the stack of applied migrations (in the `__efmigrationshistory` table) with the stack of migrations of the project.

My conclusion: as the model snapshot always considers the result of the migration stack in the project, being updated only with `Add-Migration` and `Remove-Migration`, i.e. without considering manual migration interventions, my current model snapshot will be, as of now, permanently out of sync with the actual state of my database.

I understand that this scenario could be simply resolved restoring the development database to the previous state with a backup and, of course, correctly performing manual changes in the migration so that the state don't broke. However, I wrote this question for long term reasons - I imagine that in more complex migrations cases I'll have to do a lot of manual migration interventions and, because of that, I would want to feel safe that my current database schema is at the same state of my model snapshot.

1. Should I avoid manually editing migrations to avoid causing divergence in the snapshot state and the actual database state?
2. Is there a way to sync the current state of the database with the model snapshot?
3. If not, is there a way to programmatically verify whether the state of the snapshot match the state of the database (Since Update-Database will consider only the stack of migrations and not the comparison between database current schema and snapshot)?
4. What other approaches can I use to avoid this kind of problem?

Please, correct me if I'm wrong about any conclusion that I've got or misunderstandings that I've made.

Comment: 4: Maybe it's an idea to stop using migrations altogether. I estimate that 75% of the EF questions on Stack Overflow are about migrations, indicating that it has too many points of failure. It's too hard to make it do what you want or to easy to screw up. Besides that, it's not collaboration-friendly and very restricted in which database objects it supports. We use manually generated db upgrade scripts and Visual Studio db projects to keep track of changes. Sometimes we generate new classes from database tables, sometimes we just type them. It's all so much easier.